# Convolutional Neural Networks batch size

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Question1.

Let us say the image have a shape of (batchsize=100,height=28,width=28,channel=1)

and if we put this image in the model CNN underneath,

```
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
           
            # ImgIn shape=(100, 28, 28, 1)
            #   Image shape after Conv     -> (100, 28, 28, 32)
            #    Image shape after Pool     -> (100, 14, 14, 32)
            self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    
            # second layer
            # ImgIn shape=(100, 14, 14, 32)
            #   Image shape after Conv      ->(100, 14, 14, 64)
            #   Image shape after Pool      ->(100, 7, 7, 64)
            self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    
            # THESE PART CONFUSE!!!
            self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 10, bias=True)
    
           
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc.weight)
    
        def forward(self, x):
            out = self.layer1(x)
            out = self.layer2(out)
            out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)  
            out = self.fc(out)
            return out
```

WHAT HAPPENS to the batchsize of the image after self.fc.

Is it size(batch_size=100,10)?

Qustion 2.

Also, I am confused of mini-batch. If there is 5 mini batch, and the loss is [5,-5,4,-4,0], then the average loss will be zero, then will the neural network stop training even if there is loss in each mini-batch?

Qustion 3.
Can neural network be expressed my complex matrix multiplication?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's better to ask one question at a time, this question might get closed for being unfocused.  The batch size stays the same (=100). The neural network will keep training as long as the **gradient** of the loss is nonzero. The third question is unclear.

Comment: How did you get this loss? It sees, that there is a missing part of your code. Is it a classification or regression task?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

`self.fc` is just a single linear layer. The key line here is `out.view(out.size(0), -1)` which is nothing but [flatten](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) (reshape in NumPy), where `out.size(0)` is your batch size and `-1` is all elements of the tensor (See [torch.view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html)).

In other words, this line transforms your 4d `(Batch, C, H, W)` Conv layer into 2d `(Batch, 7 * 7 * 64)`. Finally, your `fc` layer outputs `(Batch, 10)`

**Q2**

This question is confusing. How did you get this loss? It seems, that there is a missing part of your code.

**Q3**

A linear [multilayer perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) is actually a matrix multiplication. We can apply nonlinear activation function to the output of each layer (which is a result of matrix multiplication).

CNN can also be seen as a kind of matrix operation. This type of operation is called [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

So, since you have a complex network, you cannot express it as a single matrix multiplication.